# Use transistors instead of gate driver for gate drive transformer

Tags: mosfet-driver

I've been working on a solid state tesla coil project.

I have a question about the driver circuit to drive pulse transformer.

[image]

If I input a modulated or interrupted waveform on the input of the transistor base pins, can this transistor arrangment drive the gate drive transformer properly?

Comment: Are we supposed to know what "sstc" stands for? Also, define "properly" -- what do you think should happen?

Comment: Opps sorry its stands for "solid state tesla coil"

Comment: I just wanted to use this arrangemenf of transistors to drive the gate drive transformer

Answer (score 2):

> *can these transistors arrangment drive the gate drive transformer
>   properly*

Look at this: -

[image]

If \$R_L\$ represents your transformer primary then the average voltage it receives will be half of Vcc or 6 volts. You MUST NOT allow this to happen with any transformer. To remedy this put a capacitor in series with the coil to force the average voltage on the primary to be 0 volts.

Comment: Thank you very much mate

Comment: "Thanks" around here is normally seen as up-voting of answers and then finally, when you are satisfied that you have the best answer, you formally accept said answer. I mention this because I see you have asked 5 questions now and you might want to address this before it becomes too much of a hurdle @MaheshMahesh

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps adding a capacitor can solve your problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGKIWI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Okey adding a capacitor should do the job but im curious that,doesnt the capacitor will change the waveform like im planing to have two mode on my tesla coil one is musical interupter and another one is burst mode so is it gonna interupt with my signal?

Comment: The gate driver circuit shall output square pulses, it doesn't matter what kind of modulation is used. The problem is, that not always this is acheived. This capacitor coupled / decoupled (on secondary) circuit is challenging, you'd better to search in HVorg forum, or you simply change the driving circuit to full bridge.

Comment: Okey i will ask on that forum,but if i used a full bridge i need a gate driver for that and im not a veteren on electronics i know basic fundamentals about it and im still learning so thats a problem considering the lack of knowledge,but i will research and ask people who have more experience on this field,anyways thank you very much for your suggestion